# ASP.NET Core change model during ModelState check and return to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modelstate

During ModelState.IsValid check, I need to change a property of the model and then return to View. Here is how my method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveProject(MainProjectViewModel model, string id = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {    
                    bool validClientCheck = this.CheckIfClientNameAndIdAreValid(model.ProjectModel.ClientName, model.ProjectModel.ClientId);

                    if (!validClientCheck)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("ProjectModel.ClientId", $"Please select a valid client!");
                        model.ProjectModel.ClientId = null;
                    }

                    return View(model);
                }

                await this.projectService.SaveProject(model, "create");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("SaveProject", "Project", new { id = model.ProjectModel.Id });
        }
```

Even that I have `model.ProjectModel.ClientId = null;` in the view the hidden field for ClientId is still populated with the client id. How do I change the change the model before returning it to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model binding in View is not simple when you involve the validation with `ModelState`.
For a specific field in post form, you could use a key to access it in the variable `ModelState`. If you want to modify the value of that field, you should modify the value in the variable `ModelState` instead of the page `model`.

In your case, you could add codes as below:

```
// Add custom error before the model validation...
ModelState.AddModelError("ProjectModel.ClientId", $"Please select a valid client!");
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
     // Modify the value to empty
     ModelState["ProjectModel.ClientId"].RawValue = "";  //add this line after set model error
}
return View(model);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!